# redirect and remove slug if found anywhere using .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to remove **index.php/**

> example.com/index.php/apple 
>  example.com/fruits/index.php/apple
>
>  example.com/fuits/apple/index.php/ripen 
>  example.com/index.php

in any of the above cases, I need the url to be redirected by removing **index.php/**

I tried

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

But it only works for the first case from the given urls above.

Comment: You used `^` which means *start of string*. Remove it, or use `RewriteRule ^(.*/)?index\.php/(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,L]` (or something like that).

Comment: Are you hitting link `example.com/index.php/apple` in browser? If yes then what parameters you want to send to index.php?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried your suggested one, it worked for all cases except for: example.com/index.php , it should also be redirected to example.com

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 index.php/ should be removed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following htaccess rules file. Make sure to keep your file in root.

Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##Doing external redirect for index.php here.
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^index\.php/?$ /? [R=301,L]
##Doing external redirect to remove index.php here.
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?index\.php/(.*) /$1$2? [R=301,L]
##Handling home page with internal rewrite here.
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Sorry but yours after using, every pattern redirects me to example.com

Comment: @RiyaSingh, Ok sure, could you please try my edited Rules once? Let me know how it goes, make sure to clear your  browser cache before testing your URLs.

Comment: @RiyaSingh, Your welcome, happy to help. Cheers and happy learning :)